# Unable to push windows docker image to Artifactory. get manifest : null

Tags: artifactory

I am currently trying to push a windows based container to artifactory pro 5.0.1, but when I do, i get the error 'Manifest Invalid : Invalid Manifest'.

When I look at the Artifactory log, I see the following entry.

> 2018-01-15 13:12:33,280 [http-nio-8081-exec-339] [ERROR] (o.j.r.d.v.r.h.DockerV2LocalRepoHandler:291) - Error uploading manifest: 'null'

I have found a similar issue here on SO here:  [Unable to push windows docker image to Artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391385/unable-to-push-windows-docker-image-to-artifactory). but that seems to deal with foreign layer support which is marked as fixed in artifactory as of 5.0.0

Any ideas, why I am not able to push windows based containers, where linux based containers are being pushed fine?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an unrelated bug ([RTFACT-14088](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-14088)) to the foreign layer issue you mentioned that you are likely running into. Certain manifest configurations (extensions of the manifest) are not being properly interpreted. This was fixed in 5.3.0, as such upgrading may fix your issue.

Comment: We were just able to upgrade to 5.8.4. An I am now able to push my windows images. Thanks for the link to the JFrog jira.